# Blanket statement to avoid all liability

Tags: software, liability, waivers

I am currently developing an app which facilitates an [Assassin game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassin_(game)) in which players stalk and shoot their friends with water guns in order to win a monetary prize (as facilitated by whoever runs each specific game).

How can I ensure that I have no liability if a player is injured, a game host refuses to pay up, etc.

Essentially, is there any **blanket statement where the user waives all rights to sue me?**

I live in the United States.

Answer (score 3):

I like easy questions: **you can’t**.

You can limit but not eliminate liability with people you have a contract with. You can’t limit liability with third parties.

You need to consult a lawyer and buy insurance.